# Split string with double quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a file with similar lines like the following:

```
setmessage id=xxx.yyy.1 "text=Your input is not correct."
setmessage id=xxx.yyy.2 "text=Please add a ""Valid from"" date."
setmessage "id=xxx.yyy.3" "text=Another text, but the ID is in quotes too."
```

My goal is to split this text in the different attributes:

```
id   => 'xxx.yyy.1'
text => 'Your input is not correct.'

id   => 'xxx.yyy.2'
text => 'Please add a ""Valid from"" date.'

id   => 'xxx.yyy.3'
text => 'Another text, but the ID is in quotes too.'
```

What I am currently using is this:

```
function extractAttribute([String] $line, [String] $attribute){
    if ($line -like "*$attribute*"){
        $return = $line -replace ".*(?=`"$attribute=)`"$attribute=([^`"]*).*|.*$attribute=(.*?)([\r\n].*|$)", "`$1`$2"
        if ($return -eq ""){
            $return = $null
        }
        return $return
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}
```

With that code I can extract one attribute at a time. But it does not work with double quotes:

```
$line = 'setmessage id=xxx.yyy.2 "text=Please add a ""Valid from"" date."'
$attribute = "text"
$result = extractAttribute $line $attribute
```

The result is:

```
'Please add a '
```

and the rest is missing. The expected result should be:

```
'Please add a ""Valid from"" date.'
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Thanks!

Edit: I have created a poor-mans solution by replacing the bad double quotes with something else, then splitting the text and replace again. Not nice, but works:

```
function extractAttribute([String] $line, [String] $attribute){
    if ($line -like "*$attribute*"){
        $line = $line -replace '""', '~~'

        $return = $line -replace ".*(?=`"$attribute=)`"$attribute=([^`"]*).*|.*$attribute=(.*?)([\r\n ].*|$)", "`$1`$2"

        $return = $return -replace '~~', '""'
        if ($return -eq ""){
            return $null
        } else {
            return $return
        }
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add example input strings and what is your expected output

Answer (score 1):

I would consider to use the [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) cmdlet or the [`onvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7) cmdlet for this:

To set the property `Name` and `Value` based on the included `<name>=<value>` format:

```
# Import-Csv .\Input.txt -Header (0..3) -Delimiter ' ' | ForEach-Object ...
$Content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (0..3) -Delimiter ' ' | ForEach-Object {
    $Properties = @{}
    ForEach ($Item in ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value).Where{$_}) {
        $Name, $Value = $Item.Split('=',2)
        $Properties[$Name.Trim()] = "$Value".Trim()
    }
    [pscustomobject]$Properties
} | Select-Object Id, Text
```

**Results:**

```
id        text
--        ----
xxx.yyy.1 Your input is not correct.
xxx.yyy.2 Please add a "Valid from" date.
xxx.yyy.3 Another text, but the ID is in quotes too.
```

Comment: your decision is not very suitable because the author of the post indicated that it should not contain words `id=` and `text=`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this changes without function:

```
$line = 'setmessage id=xxx.yyy.2 "text=Please add a ""Valid from"" date."'
$attribute = "text="
$result=$line -replace ".*(?<=$attribute)" #select all to and of your attribute and replace it  to nothing
```

**Additional (if you read your data from file)**:

```
$pattern1="(?<=id=).*?((?=\s)|(?=`"))"
$pattern2="(?<=text=).*(?=`")"
$customdata=@()
$z=Get-Content D:\testdir\sample.txt |ForEach-Object{
$customdata+=[PSCustomObject]@{
ID=$_ |Select-String $pattern1|foreach{$_.Matches.value}
text=$_ |Select-String $pattern2|foreach{$_.Matches.value}
}
}
```

Now `$customdata` is array that have two properties `ID` and `text` and you can get data from it by `$customdata.ID` `$customdata.text`.If you need write some output you run it in foreach loop and formating your output.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. That would work with the attribute "text" as it is the last one. But it would not work with the attribute "id" or if the attributes are mixed (to be fair, I didn't mention this in the question).

Comment: ***(to be fair, I didn't mention this in the question)***, please update your question and  **do** add this to the question, so that it in not hidden in specific comments of answers.